# Is it possible to add google and Facebook authentication with firebase?

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-oauth, expo, facebook-oauth

I'm building an app with react native and firebase. I want to know if there is any way to implement both Facebook and Google auth.
I'm using expo init cli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

For Google auth : https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin

For Facebook auth : https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/facebook-login